# PHP Mail Sending Issue

Tags: phpmailer, php

I'm having a hard time getting the following code to run:

```
$name = 'Kevin';
$company = 'nonw';
$website = 'none';
$email = 'my@email.com';
$phone = 'none';
$message = 'Just a test message.';

$message = "<ul>
            <li><strong>From:</strong> $name</li>
            <li><strong>Company:</strong> $company</li>
            <li><strong>Website:</strong> $website</li>
            <li><strong>Email:</strong> $email</li>
            <li><strong>Phone:</strong> $phone</li>
        </ul>
        <p>$message</p>";

$subject = '[' . $sitename . '] New contact message from ' . $name . ' ( ' . $email . ' )';

$headers = 'From: ' . $sitename . ' <' . $to . '>\r\nReply-To: ' . $email . '\r\n';

$s = mail($subject, $message, $email, $to);
if($s){
echo '<div class="msg">Your message has been sent.  Thank you for contacting us, someone will be in touch soon.</div>';
}else{
echo '<div class="err">There was an error sending your message.  Please try again later.</div>';
print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

I have this in my php.ini:

```
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f my@email.com"
```

Have also tried with:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

I have verified that the server is setup correctly to send email by running this directly on the server `echo "test" | mail -s "test mail" my@email.com` and I received the email.

What can be going on, or more to the point...  what am I missing?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run your script? Which div displays? Try adding a `var_dump()` for your individual variables before you're making the `mail()` call to make sure you're passing the correct information.

Comment: i'm a dolt....   you'll see why in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys.   I had it spelt wrong in mailconfig.ini

changing `"/urs/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f my@email.com"` to `"/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f my@email.com"` did the trick